# Is it possible to replace the video card in IBM Lenevo Thinkpad w510?

Tags: video, thinkpad

I have IBM Thinkpad W510.

When I turn it on, I get `1 long beep and 2 short beeps with no display`

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T61-and-prior-T-series-ThinkPad/T61p-exhibiting-1-long-and-2-short-beep-and-black-screen/td-p/223574/page/2

This code means the GPU failure.

Now my warranty is expired. Is there any way i can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Detach all connected (USB) cables, and try rebooting. I had similar issue with Logitech wireless mouse, when receiver plugged to usb2: unpluging receiver & rebooting or booting receiver unplugged sloved it for me. For me it happens irregular.